# How to expand a dataframe's row based on one column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to come up with a program that creates multiple rows and columns for each row based on a value in a column.

Here's a look at my data

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("test data.xlsx")
```

| Id | # of weeks | Manhours | StartDate | EndDate | Starting Year | Starting Week period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 2 | 10 | 1/15/2023 | 1/29/2023 | 2023 | 3 |
| bbb | 3 | 12 | 2/12/2023 | 3/05/2023 | 2023 | 7 |

The table needs to be expanded so that every row is expanded by the number of weeks.
There needs to be columns added for the Labor hours per week and columns which count the number of weeks for each Id.

The results should look like this

| Id | # of weeks | Manhours | StartDate | EndDate | Starting Year | Starting Week period | Week Count | Labor | Week # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 2 | 10 | 1/15/2023 | 1/29/2023 | 2023 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 3 |
| aaa | 2 | 10 | 1/15/2023 | 1/29/2023 | 2023 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 4 |
| bbb | 3 | 12 | 2/12/2023 | 3/05/2023 | 2023 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 7 |
| bbb | 3 | 12 | 2/12/2023 | 3/05/2023 | 2023 | 7 | 2 | 4 | 8 |
| bbb | 3 | 12 | 2/12/2023 | 3/05/2023 | 2023 | 7 | 3 | 4 | 10 |

I've been able to get the table in the format I needed by doing the following:

```
# Expand the number of rows by the number of weeks for each job record
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df["# of weeks"])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

However there's some more issues.

I've added the following columns

```
# Add column for cumulative number of weeks for each expanded job record row    
df['Week Count'] = df.groupby(['Id']).cumcount() + 1 

# Add column for year for each job record row
df['Year'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
                   (df['Starting Year'] + 1),
                    df['Starting Year'])

# Add column for the week number for the calendar year for each job record row
df['Week #'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
                   (df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-53),
                    df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1)

# Add a column Period which concatenates the Year and Week # columns 
df['Period'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + "-" + df['Week #'].astype(str)
```

This presents some issues because the Year and Week # columns will only reset if a record continues past only 1 calendar year. They will not reset if it goes past 2 or more calendar years.

I've attempted the following

```
# Add column for number of week for each expanded job record row
df['Week Count'] = df.groupby(['Id']).cumcount() + 1 

# Add column for year for each job record row
from math import floor
df['Year'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
                   df['Starting Year'] + floor((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count'])/52),
                   df['Starting Year'])

# Add column for the number of week for the calendar year for each job record row
df['Week #'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
                   (df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-53),
                    df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1)

# Add leading 0 to the Week # Column
df['Week #'] = df['Week #'].astype(str).str.pad(2, side = 'left', fillchar = '0')

# Add a column Period which concatenates the Year and Week #  columns 
df['Period'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + "-" + df['Week  #'].astype(str)
```

However, This is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 7
      4 # Add column for year for each job record row
      5 from math import floor
      6 df['Year'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
----> 7                        df['Starting Year'] + floor((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count'])/52), 
      8                        df['Starting Year'])
     10 # Add column for the number of week for the calendar year for each job record row
     11 df['Week #'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
     12                        (df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-53),
     13                         df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:191, in _coerce_method.<locals>.wrapper(self)
    189 if len(self) == 1:
    190     return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 191 raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to apply function for float number to pandas series, they are difference types

I recommend you to use `.astype(int)`. It will round in the same way as `math.floor`

```
df['Year'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
               df['Starting Year'] + ((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']) / 52).astype(int),
               df['Starting Year'])
```

You also can use `numpy` library, for applying different types or rounding

```
import numpy as np
df['column'].apply(np.ceil)
df['column'].apply(np.floor)
```

But in your case, you have to still apply `.astype(int)` because `np` applying doesn't change type of series data

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([(.21, .32), (.01, .67), (.66, .03), (.21, .18)],
...                   columns=['dogs', 'cats'])
>>> df['dogs'].apply(np.floor)
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
Name: dogs, dtype: float64
enter code here
```

And it will affect your results

```
    Id  # of weeks  Manhours  ......    Year Week #     Period
0  aaa           2        10  ......  2023.0     03  2023.0-03
1  aaa           2        10  ......  2023.0     04  2023.0-04
2  bbb           3        12  ......  2023.0     07  2023.0-07
3  bbb           3        12  ......  2023.0     08  2023.0-08
4  bbb           3        12  ......  2023.0     09  2023.0-09
```

I hope it was helpful!

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I was able to fix my Year column using `as.type(int)`

I noticed my Week # column resets back to 1 from 52 after the first calendar year, but continues past 52 for 2 or more years.